# What is wrong with this PHP expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Can someone explain to me why the following returns empty arrays?

```
$reg = "/(\[{(false|true)};{.+};{\d}\])+/";
preg_match_all($reg,"[{false};{abcde};{10}][{true};{fghij};{10}]",$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written `\d` when it should be `\d+`:

```
$reg = "/(\[{(false|true)};{.+};{\d+}\])+/";
preg_match_all($reg,"[{false};{abcde};{10}][{true};{fghij};{10}]",$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Although it doesn't seem to matter in your case, I'd also escape the braces, as they are special characters.

```
$reg = "/(\[\{(false|true)\};\{.+\};\{\d+\}\])+/";
```

Answer (score 2):

\d should be \d+ for one